# navigation bar disappear after adding prepare function

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am woking on an recording APP.

I tried to add navigation controller in my first recording viewcontroller which then could pass filename array to the second viewcontroller using the following function prepare:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let controller = segue.destination as? MainViewController
    controller?.recordArray = recordingArray
    self.present(controller!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

However, when ran in the simulator the navigation bar disappeared in the second controller and Xcode pops out the warning

> Thread1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2,address=0x7fff51edfff8)

Has anyone got any advice?
Thanks!

Comment: Why are you force unwrapping the controller when presenting?

Comment: No, actually, why are you even presenting in that method? All you should be doing is configuring the destaonation view controller before the segue does the presentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't ever call `present(_:animated:completion:)` inside `prepare(for segue:)`.

`prepare(for segue)` is called automatically by the system just before a segue is about to happen to let you prepare the data for sending to the destination viewcontroller or do any other calculations you need to before performing the segue. A segue needs to be set up in Storyboard and it will either be called automatically or if it is a manual segue, you need to call it using `perform(segue)` and once you do that, the system will call `prepare(for segue)` for you. You can see why calling another navigation function proves to be problematic, since you are trying to navigate to another viewcontroller using two different methods (segue and present).

If you haven't set up the segue in Storyboard, then you also need to do that, since if it is not set up, `let controller = segue.destination as? MainViewController` will be `nil`.

Once you set up the segue in Storyboard, this is how your function should look like:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let controller = segue.destination as? MainViewController {
        controller.recordArray = recordingArray
        self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn’t be trying to present a VC in this method, it’s just a place for you to configure the destination VC before the segue presents it

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let controller = segue.destination as? MainViewController else { return }
    controller.recordArray = recordingArray
}
```